# Issues linking R to talk to Google Analytics

Tags: r, google-analytics

I've been trying to link a work based Google Analytics account to a work based laptop with R installed - over the Corporate internet. I've created a Google API and installed library(googleAnalyticsR). When I run...

```
ga_auth()
```

I get the following...

> ga_auth()
>   Waiting for authentication in browser...
>   Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
>   Authentication complete.
>   Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
>     Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds

This appears after I've had the Google Analytics web based pop-up requesting access, which I approve.

Details:
Windows 7 Professional
RAM 8Gb
Operating System 64 bit

Any ideas?

Comment: Can we see some of your code? And where do you get the error (in your terminal, in the browser? It sounds like that the error could be several places, but I'm not sure. Have you tried a different browser (I don't know if browsers have some sort of 'quality-assurance' of some sort. And is it a local environment or deployed on a server? If it's local, - then which local server are you using? ... Another shot from the hip is that it may be another program blocking the port that `ga_auth` are trying to use. You could list all ports used and see if something looks suspicious. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Zeth thanks for your response. Found the issue. Corporate Firewall. Unplugged the network cable, used the public network and it all worked like a dream.